# Drag an obj file using three js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am using a Three js Draggable cubes example which is [this](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_interactive_draggablecubes.html).

I want to replace the internally created cubes with the obj files. Here is what I am doing.

I have added the obj model(a human face) to the objects[], so I think now it is a part of all the objects and should be intersected by a ray.

I am not able to drag the 3D obj model but I am able to drag the other cubes.
Does the Raycaster not intersect 3d obj Model? How can I drag the obj model in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to make through this [example](http://alexan0308.github.io/threejs/examples/#misc_controls_events).

```
<script src="js/controls/EventsControls.js"></script>

EventsControls = new EventsControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
EventsControls.projectionMap = checkerboard;
EventsControls.fixed.y = true;  

var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();

loader.load( 'models/objmtl/model.obj', 'models/objmtl/model.mtl',
    function ( GingerbreadMan ) {
        GingerbreadMan.position.set( 125, 35, 175 );
        GingerbreadMan.scale.set( 1/3, 1/3, 1/3 );
        scene.add( GingerbreadMan );

        EventsControls.attach( GingerbreadMan );
    }
);

//

function render() {
       EventsControls.update();
       controls.update();
       renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the link, this example really looks like what I need. But I downloaded the latest version of three js(r70) and I couldn't find this example in that and also I couldn't find "EventsControls.js" in that.
Where can I find that?

Comment: [here](http://alexan0308.github.io/threejs/examples/js/controls/EventsControls.js)

Comment: I need to drag objects on the ipad. How can I do that? Is there another event I can use?