# Three.js mouse picking, 3D model with OBJMTLLoader

Tags: three.js

i started programing with Three.js. Now i have a problem, when i load an Object with the OBJMTLLoader i dont get any access to change the position of the object with mouseMove. I have pushed the obects into the objects array but it doesnt work. If anybody could help or knowes a good tutorial would be really fine. I hope the structure how i wrote the question is clear....its the first time i´m using stacko.

These are my variables and the function i try to change the objects:

```
var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();

var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();

var objects = [];

function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {

    event.preventDefault();

    mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;

    raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse,camera);

    intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(objects);

    if (intersects.length> 0) {
        intersects[0].object.position.set(5, 5 ,5);
    }

}
```

Here i load the object with the OBJMTLLoader....this works:)

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();

loader.load('models/sofa4.obj', 'models/sofa4.mtl', function(object) {

    // console.log(object);
    object.traverse(function(child) {

        if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
            child.material.shininess = 0;
         // console.log(child.material);
        }

    });

    object.position.z = 2;
    object.position.y = -5.95;
    object.scale.set(0.05,0.05,0.05);
    scene.add(object);
    objects.push(object);

});
```

Comment: You can use eventscontrols http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28115792/drag-an-obj-file-using-three-js/28117540#28117540

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, the first try didn´t work but i will experiement more with it and i´m full of hope that it will work!

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22228203/picking-object3d-loaded-via-objmtlloader. (Although I haven't got it working myself yet).